# What is the name of this connector component?

Tags: connector, identification

First of all, I recognise how hopelessly difficult it will be for other users to find this question based on a StackExchange search. Such is the nature of image-based questions.

In any event, I'm looking to identify this connector, in order that I can buy another one. For reference, in this application at least, it's part of a 3.6V battery charging mechanism.

[image]

Comment: Ever heard of the popular image edit functionality of "cropping"?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Image now cropped for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: You can make the question more searchable by describing the object in words - "what is this white plastic latched two-pin connector with 4.2 mm spacing."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is a 2-pin Molex "Mini-Fit Jr." nylon line plug

There are other, generic, manufacturers - but I'm providing a specific name brand as I don't see that any of the generic versions have a specific name. Searching for ATX style or EPS style may help.

Comment: Yeah, but which Molex nylon line plug? Molex is a huge manufacturer with countless plug types.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Added more details, hope they help.

Comment: I believe @Trashman is correct, it looks like a Molex Mini-Fit Jr. to me (I use them all the time at work). It is either that or a Micro-fit (It's a bit difficult to tell the scale from the image) but I am pretty sure it's a mini-fit.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are many brands, so I cannot give you a specific name, most of the time I see such connectors on RC car batteries. If your are looking for purchasing one I recommend you to check RC Hobby or model sport shops.

- Such as [this](http://www.rcplanet.com/DuraTrax_6_Cell_Connector_Set_Kyosho_Standard_p/dtxc2240.htm) might be suitable.
- Or [this](http://www.rcplanet.com/Connector_Tamiya_Type_p/mmrctmf.htm).

  [image]
- Or [this](http://www.modelsport.co.uk/etronix-tamiya-male-and-female-connector-with-crimps/rc-car-products/393575) from another shop.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like one of these: -

[image]

Available from [**here**](http://www.banggood.com/Male-Connector-Plug-2-Female-Terminals-For-Optimate-Accumate-Battery-Charger-p-1025067.html). You'll probably need a crimping tool or maybe you can solder the wires up to the crimps successfully. Also from [here](http://www.vetco.net/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=16770)